# How to most effectively combine functions including checkprime

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
......................
int checkprime ( char number )
{
    int i, valid;
    valid = TRUE;

    for ( i = 2; i <= number; i++ )
    {
        if ( number % i == 0 ) valid = FALSE;
    } 
    return valid;

}

int main(void)

{
    char inputarray[4];
    int c, primeanswer;

   ........................
    {
        primeanswer = checkprime(c);

        if ( primeanswer == 1)
        {
            printf("%d", "is a prime", inputarray);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d", "not prime", inputarray);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue here is trying to get the checkprime function working. I think I'm probably not initialising something as the numbers I'm getting seem to me like the program output isn't correct. Also when I do enter data for checkprime the numbers to me seem like uninitialised int values. And that the other functions don't seem to be called.

What is it that I am not initialising?
How can I combine the checkprime function more effectively with the others? Is it necessary to switch between char/int values as I've done in the functions?

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

................
}
int checkprime ( int number )
{
int i, valid;
valid = TRUE;

for ( i = 2; i < number; i++ )
    {
        if ( number % i == 0 ) valid = FALSE;
    } 
        return valid;

}

int main(void)

{
char inputarray[4];
int c, primeanswer;
.........................

else  
{
 c = atoi(inputarray);

primeanswer = checkprime(c);

if ( primeanswer == 1)
{
    printf("%d", "is a prime", inputarray);
}
else
{
    printf("%d", "not prime", inputarray);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `c` to `checkprime`, but you never set it to anything.  As a result, the contents of `c` are undefined and trying to read it results in undefined behavior.

Pass your array to the `atoi` function to convert it to an integer and assign it to `c`.  You should also change the type of the `number` parameter in `checkprime` to `int` to match what is being passed in.

It also looks like you're missing an `else`:

```
    if ( !checknumeric(inputarray)) 
{
    printf("Invalid input");
}
// else goes here
{
    primeanswer = checkprime(c);
    ...
```

EDIT:

More issues with your code:

You're not printing the results correctly:

```
printf("%d", "is a prime", inputarray);
...
printf("%d", "not prime", inputarray);
```

There are two issues with these.  First, the fixed portion of the string to print is the first parameter to `printf`.  The rest get substituted in.  So the first two parameters should be combined into a single string.  Second, you use `%d` to print at `int` but `inputarray` is a `char` array.  You should instead pass in `c`, which is the integer value you want to print.

```
printf("%d is a prime", c);
...
printf("%d not prime", c);
```

Comment: Can I write the syntax like this? inputarray[4] = atoi(c);

Comment: @Absolutebeginnertoc No, you're trying to use `c` without setting it to anything again.  What you want is `c=atoi(inputarray);`.  Don't forget to fix the parameter type of `checkprime`, and also fix the loop condition as mentioned in Haldean Brown's answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've adjusted it tho still appearing as undefined behaviour when I try it out. Will edit my original post with what I have now.

Comment: @Absolutebeginnertoc Be sure to leave the original code so the existing answers don't lose context.

Comment: Thanks dbush. I've altered the code as above. I note that should be c not inputarray as I had already set c to be the integer value of inputarray. Now I think my logic is awry, I'm constantly getting 0 is prime despite any number I try. Is my logic for function for checkprime correct?

Comment: @Absolutebeginnertoc You altered how you get input.  You're now reading a single character into `c` with `scanf`, storing the character's ASCII code.  You're already reading the characters you want with `checkmore3`, so get rid of the `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

dbush's answer is correct, but you're still going to get the result that you're already seeing, because you have a bug in your `checkprime` method:

```
int checkprime ( char number )
{
    int i, valid;
    valid = TRUE;
    for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) valid = FALSE;
    } 
    return valid;
}
```

Your problem is that `number % number == 0` for all values of `number`, and you let `i` iterate up to `number` by using `<=` in your for-loop condition. Changing your for loop to:

```
    for (i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) valid = FALSE;
    }
```

Will fix the logic there.